# $\epsilon-\delta$ argument for continuity for $f(x) = \sin(x)$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Given
$$\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = L$$
We want to show that $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ such that 
$$|x-c| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L | < \epsilon$$

Our $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and our $c=0$, and $L=0$. So, we suppose 
$|x|<\delta$ and need to show $|\sin(x)|<\epsilon$.

My teacher did this by drawing a picture and showing it holds, but I wanted to see how it would work strictly algebraically.

Comment: In order to conduct a rigorous proof, you would need to start from a _precise definition_ of what $\sin x$ means. Do you have one?

Comment: Are infinite series allowed?

Comment: hint  $\lvert$ $sinx$ $\rvert$ $\le$ $ \vert$ $x$ $\rvert$

Comment: The typical method is to take the taylor series for sine as the definition of the sine function...continuity is then automatic from theorems on infinite series.

Answer (score 0):

hint: consider $g(x)=x-sin(x)$. $g'(x)=1-cos(x) \ge 0$ which means that $g(x)$ is increasing and because $g(0)=0$ we conclude that $x - sin (x) \ge 0$

Comment: If you're going to assume that $\sin$ is differentiable, then continuity is automatic.

Answer (score -1):

As was already written, it depends on definition of sine.
But if we suppose y-coordinate of point of unit circle as definition,
it is obvious that for $\varepsilon>1$ is any $\delta$ good
and if $0<\varepsilon<1$ then $\delta=\inf{\{t;t>0\wedge \sin{\left(t\right)}>\varepsilon\}}$

Comment: Nothing is obvious. Consider explaining the details of your answer, since it is "obvious" to me, that the OP does not get it that easily.

Comment: I mean listen, it's also pretty obvious that the sine function is continuous at zero, but since we're all here, we may as well do some math.

Comment: Obvious is that for $\varepsilon>1$ is any $\delta$ good because implication $\left|\sin{\left(x\right)}\right|\geq\varepsilon >1 \Rightarrow \left|x\right|\geq\delta$ is true vacously. Maybe I should write "." between "good" and "and"